# how do i access each item of an array stored in local storage individually?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

The code below fetches images and their names from a food api. I am able to store to those images in the local storage once a user hits the like button .i however want to get back the stored image and name data and display them in a favorite tab. But I can't seem to be able to achieve that..Any help?

```
        let myFavMeals=[]
   function getRandomMeal(){
 fetch('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random? 
  number=10&apiKey=b354ffb530c5444da1eec4b02a3146be').then((data)=>{
  console.log(data)
  return data.json()
   }).then((completedata)=>{
 console.log(completedata.recipes)
  let data1=""
  completedata.recipes.forEach((recipe) => {
    const {
      id,
      title,
      readyInMinutes,
      extendedIngredients,
      servings,
      image,
      dishTypes,
      instructions,
    } = recipe;
      data1+=`  
      <div class="meal-header">
          <img src=${recipe.image} alt=${recipe.title} >
      </div>
      <div class="meal-body">
          <h6>${recipe.title}</h6>
          <p class="show">see recipes</p>
          <button class="fav-btn">
              <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="holder">
      <div class="meal-desc">
      <p>ready in : ${recipe.readyInMinutes} minutes</p>
      <center><h6>instructions</h6></center>
      <p>${recipe.instructions}  </p>
      </div>
      </div>`      
    })
    const meal=document.querySelector(".meal")
    meal.innerHTML=data1
   const holder=document.querySelector(".holder")
const show=document.querySelectorAll(".show")
show.forEach(shows=>{
    showcounter=0
    shows.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      holder.style.display="block"
      showcounter++
      if(showcounter== 2) {
      holder.style.display="none"
      }
    })
  })
const favBtns=meal.querySelectorAll(".fav-btn i")
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.meal-header > img')
favBtns.forEach((favBtn,i)=>{
  favBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    favBtn.classList.add("active")
    console.log(images[i].src, images[i].alt)     
    myFavMeals.push(images[i].src, images[i].alt)
    localStorage.setItem("myFavMeals", JSON.stringify(myFavMeals))
    showMeal()
})
})
      
 }).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err)
    })
}
getRandomMeal()
    function showMeal(){
      let favmeal= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myFavMeals"))
      favmeal.forEach(favmeals=>{
        let meallist=""   
        meallist+=`<ul>
             <li><img src=${favmeal} alt=${favmeal[i].alt}><span>${favmeal[i].alt}</span></li>
         </ul>`
       
         document.querySelector(".fav-meals").innerHTML+=meallist
      })
       

      }
```

Comment: Please show [mre], it will greatly improve chances for help. But anyway since you are doing stringify do parse on retrieving and access it like normal JSON objects...

Comment: You're storing an array like this: `[image_url, alt_text, image_url, alt_text, ...]`, but your iteration over it when you get it from local storage does not match this structure at all. If you want to keep this array structure you need to iterate with a plain `for` loop having the step of 2. But it would be better to store an array of objects instead: `[{image_url, alt_text}, {image_url, alt_text}...]`

Comment: Also, while you need a reproducible example, DO NOT post code with API keys -- they are your private keys, perhaps even paid for, so you don't want them to be publicly exposed.

Comment: @ tromgy noted. However could you show that with a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the favorites in the array as objects using object literal:

```
myFavMeals.push({src: images[i].src, alt: images[i].alt})
```

And then access them in the loop using the keys `src` and `alt`:

```
function showMeal() {
  let favmeal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myFavMeals"));
  favmeal.forEach(favmeal => {
    let meallist = "";
    meallist += `<ul>
             <li><img src=${favmeal.src} alt=${favmeal.alt}><span>${favmeal.alt}</span></li>
         </ul>`;

    document.querySelector(".fav-meals").innerHTML += meallist;
  });
}
```

Comment: Works as expected